# Azure Data Factory v2 - OData - Copy Data - XmlError hexadecimal value 0x1F is an invalid character Line 1, position 1

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Here is a sample OData URL format used:

https://odata-my-company.net/api/v1/datalake/abcd1234321234ef9887492023/data_tablename/

I have tried using Encoded URL as well substituting ":" as "%3A" and "/" as "%2F"

Also tried removing "https://" altogether.
Also tried using "http://" instead of "https://"

Nothing works.

Any help??? Thanks in advance

=== Error Message Below ===

Connection failed

Failed to create OData connection to RequestUrl
The metadata document could not be read from the message content.
XmlError : '', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1. : (1, 1)

[Screenshot of same error in Azure Data Factory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh24B.png)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the url . The error complains about the XML . I know that in ADF we have json all over the place . Just curious if the ODATA is returning XML and you have an issue there . To me it looks like you are looking at the wrong place .